# SPOJ - Aggressive cows, what is the meaning of "largest minimum distance" terminology?

Tags: c, arrays, binary-search

I'm trying to understand the problem of [AGGRCOW - Aggressive cows](https://www.spoj.com/problems/AGGRCOW/cstart=30) in Spoj. But how this output has come, I don't get it. First I thought maybe the distance between them like for this input:

> ```
> Input:
> 5 3 
> 1 2 4 8 9
> ```
>
> Ouput: 3

first we put, cow1 in position arr[0], then we put cow2 in arr[2]. We don't put cow2 in arr[1](https://www.spoj.com/problems/AGGRCOW/cstart=30) because then there will be no distance between them (2-1=1). Distance of cow2 and cow1 is 3 units now. So for that we put cow2 in arr[2]. And finally we put cow3 in arr[3] as distance between cow3 and cow2 is here 4. And then we compare this 3<4. This outputs 3.

But when I tried to apply same logic for this input:

> ```
> Input:
> 6 3 
> 2 3 4 5 8 9
> ```
>
> Ouput: 3

In my logic it should be 2.  As if we keep cow1 in arr[0] and cow2 in arr[2] then distance is 4-2=2. And it's minimum. But when I want to see what should be the actual value by googling I found out that it is 3. I dont understand how it is 3. Why not 2?  I just want the explanation of this problem, not the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are given *N* stall locations, *a*<sub>0</sub> through *a*<sub>*N*-1</sub>. You must fill *C* of those, but so that the separation between the filled stall numbers is as high as possible. The output is the separation fulfilled by all filled stalls.  That is, if you output 3, it means your solution says *"I can fill in the stalls so that the distance between any two filled stalls is at least 3"*.

If you think about it, you really are looking at the minimum distance between any two filled stalls, and you are trying to maximize it, without compromising the distance to any other filled stalls. Thus: largest minimum distance.

The input is of form

> *N* *C*
>   *a*<sub>0</sub> *a*<sub>1</sub> ... *a*<sub>*N*-2</sub> *a*<sub>*N*-1</sub>

The second example is

```
6 3 
2 3 4 5 8 9
```

meaning there are 6 stalls: 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, and 9, and three of them need to be filled, maintaining maximum separation between stall numbers.

The optimum solution is to use stalls 2, 5, and 9. The separations are then 5-2 = 3 and 9-5 = 4, and the result is the smallest of them, 3.

Comment: suppose, n = 5, c = 3. stalls are 8,12,15,17,20. It's o/p is 5.

keeping cows in these position 8, 12, 17 can give 8-12 = 4 and 17-12 = 5, But why we still choose 5 here?

Comment: ok what i understand is, first I have to find out the optimal position and then from these position I have to take the minimum distance. right?

Comment: @WinnieA: No, you put the cows in 8, 15, and 20; so the separations are 15-8 = 7 and 20 - 15 = 5.

Comment: When you select the positions, you are trying to keep each used stall as far away from other stalls as possible, considering all used stalls at the same time. You need to pick a set of stalls that lets you say *"There is at least L between used stall numbers"*, with the largest *L* you can manage; then output that *L*.

Comment: @ NominalAnimal ok, got it. You mean the optimal positions

Comment: @WinnieA: Yes, of course. It wouldn't be a puzzle if you could pick *any* configuration and return its properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the case 6 3, 2 3 4 5 8 9, the cows could be put in 2, 5, and 8, yielding a minimum distance of 3. That is a larger minimum than 2, so 2 is not the largest minimum possible.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, what do you mean by larger minimum 2?

Comment: @WinnieA: If you put the cows in 2, 5, and 8, the minimum distance between them is 3. If you put the cows in 2, 4, and 8, the minimum distance between them is 2. The problem asks for the largest minimum. 3 is larger than 2.

Answer (score 0):

> To prevent the cows from hurting each other, FJ wants to assign the cows to the stalls, such that the minimum distance between any two of them is as large as possible.

FJ has to put the cows **as far apart from each other** as possible - the distance between two cows/stall locations in that setup is the largest minimum distance.

In the given stall locations and given number of cows, you've to choose the stall locations such that all the cows would be accommodated in the stalls which are most distant from each other (minimum distance is the distance between two stall locations where you assign given cows). The distance between two of the nearest stalls in that setup is the largest minimum distance.